# Cannot read SEQUENCE value with WHERE clause in HSQLDB?

Tags: hsqldb

I was trying to get value based on the sequence number using WHERE clause,

However, it is returning Blank result.

I have tried both

```
select report_time from DATA
where idx = 1;
```

and

```
select report_time from DATA
where idx = '1';
```

Has anyone encounter this issue before in HSQLDB?

```
create sequence SEQID2 start with 1 increment by 1;

create view DATA as 
select next value for SEQID2 AS idx, report_time
FROM abc;

select report_time from DATA
where idx = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you execute `SELECT * FROM DATA` the query returns larger values for the `idx` column. The rows of the VIEW are not stable, therefore your query has no practical usage.

Comment: Understood,

Is there any work around that you would suggest in this case?

Comment: If you explain what you want the query to do, there is usually a solution.